# Replace data labels in ggplot2 heatmap with actual column names in a shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Hello I have a simple shiny app which creates a heatmap. The problem is that after I melt the initial dataset into "gen3" I get label names like `gen3[,1]: DADA` but I want to take `gene_symbol: DATA` instead (I want the same with the other labels as well). Is this possible with ggplot2? I assume I should use `paste()` somehow or manually change the labels.

```
#data
gene_symbol<-c("DADA","SDAASD","SADDSD","SDADD")
ASDDA<-c("normal","over","low","over")
ASDDb<-c("normal","over","low","over")
ASDDAf<-c("normal","over","low","over")
Gene_states2<-data.frame(gene_symbol,ASDDA,ASDDb,ASDDAf)

#ui.r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(extrafont)
library(dplyr)

fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel(div("GENES HEATMAP",style = "color:blue")),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(width = 3

    ),
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Heatmap",

                           fluidRow(
                             tags$style(type="text/css",
                                        ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
                                        ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"

                             ),
                             plotlyOutput("sc")
                           )


                  ))
      )))
#server.r
function(input, output,session) {
```

rt<-reactive({
    req(input$file1)

```
csvdata <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                    header = input$header

)

if(input$disp == "head"){
  head(csvdata)
} else{
  csvdata
} 

row.has.na <- apply(csvdata, 1, function(x){any(is.na(x))})
csvdata2 <- csvdata[!row.has.na,]

csvdata2
```

})

```
  output$sc<-renderPlotly({
    library(ggplot2); library(reshape2)
    gen3 <- melt(rt(), id.var = colnames(rt())[1])
    p1<-ggplot(gen3, aes(gen3[,1],gen3[,2])) + geom_tile(aes(fill = gen3[,3]),
                                                         colour = "white") + scale_fill_manual(values=c("yellow", "red", "blue"))+
      labs(x = "gene_symbol",y="sample",fill="value")+
      theme(title = element_text(family = "Calibri", 
                                 size = 10, 
                                 face = "bold"), 
            axis.title = element_text(family = "Calibri Light", 
                                      size = 16, 
                                      face = "bold", 
                                      color = "black"), 
            axis.text = element_text(family = "Calibri", 
                                     size = 11),
            axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 25, b = 0, l = 25)),
            panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
            panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey50"))
    ggplotly(p1)%>%
      layout( autosize = F, width = 1450, height = 600,hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white",
                                                                         font = list(family = "Calibri", 
                                                                                     size = 9, 
                                                                                     color = "black")))

  })  

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ggplot there is no need to specify the data.frame name in aesthetics (aes) after you've already told it which data.frame to use.

Simply do this:
`ggplot(gen3, aes(gene_symbol, variable)) + geom_tile(aes(fill= value)` ... and so on.

If you don't want `variable` and `value` to show up in your hoverlabel, just change colnames of gen3 after you melt it to whatever you do want to show up.

Comment: You answer works for my example here but not for my actual case. My dataset comes as a csv input and is includes into a reactive expression so I get an error Warning: Error in : Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (420): fill, x, y

Comment: hmm, so what class is your gen3 and what does it look like exactly? Have you tried casting it to a data.frame? `gen3 <- as.data.frame(melt(...))` usually problems like these are a class issue and can be solved with the right casting

Comment: It is a data.frame I checked it

Comment: ok try this, instead of having rt as a reactive function, read in your .csv inside the renderPlotly function, then use csvdata instead of rt(). Also do read.csv(..., stringsAsFactors =FALSE)

Comment: Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: Yes by setting the colnames. Tnx

Comment: Great! No problem